# Radial gradient in CSS

Tags: css, gradient, radial-gradients

Can somebody tell me how I configure radial gradient in CSS to exactly look like the following background.

[image: Background image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS code from [gradientfinder](http://gradientfinder.com):

```css
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(20, 17, 25) 0%, rgb(69, 61, 52) 80%, rgb(57, 50, 45) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(20, 17, 25) 0%, rgb(69, 61, 52) 80%, rgb(57, 50, 45) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgb(20, 17, 25) 0%, rgb(69, 61, 52) 80%, rgb(57, 50, 45) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(20, 17, 25) 0%, rgb(69, 61, 52) 80%, rgb(57, 50, 45) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(20, 17, 25) 0%, rgb(69, 61, 52) 80%, rgb(57, 50, 45) 100%);
}
```